# Drawing a Rectangle of Size 2X2 Inches -Inches to Pixel Conversion

Tags: c#, printing, gdi+, system.drawing

I need to draw a rectangle that should be around the size 2X2 Inches when printed on a paper.

I know that i can draw a rectangle using

```
 g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100,100, 100, 200);
```

This application will only be used in computers.How can i convert the inches to pixels properly so that i can get the desired dimensions when printed.

Comment: All depending on the DPI (Dots Per Inch) setting on your printer. When you sent the document to print you should be able to specify the DPI you want so that will make it a bit easier. Basically, if you have the printer at 100dpi for example, then you want to draw you rectangle 2000 x 2000 (20 x 100)... of course you will need paper big enough for that. Your standard A4 wont fit it on

Comment: @musefan Sorry it was 2X2 Inches.

Comment: ha, well just recalculate then... [DPI setting] x [Length in Inches] = [Number of Pixels]

Comment: @musefan But how does Photoshop produce perfect sized photos for printing

Comment: Use e.g.: `e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
            e.Graphics.PageScale = 0.001f;`

Comment: @TaW Can you please tell me what does this do

Comment: @techno: Sorry, I don't work for Adobe, why don't you email them and ask them for their source code

Comment: It refers to the Graphics object you use for printing. You called it `g`  in your code. It needs to know a few things for working with your printer. The unit is what unit you want to use; as a European I usually use mm. The Scale then adapts the unit to the numbers you want to use, which was 1/1000th inches...

Comment: @musefan Good idea.Will send one now :P

Comment: @TaW If i simply create the JPEG containing the rectangle and leave the user to print it,can i place a rectangle in it such that after printing and measuring physically it is 2X2 Inches.

Comment: If you want the user to do the printing it is necessary to set the bitmaps's dpi to something that results in the desired size. So if you want it to come out in 2x2 inches and it has NxM pixels you need to set the dpix to 2N and dpiY to 2M. These are Bitmap properties that get saved along with the image. The user can still make the printing software to change the output size but by default it should come out right.

Comment: @TaW Thanks.But do you mean to set the DPI of the whole image containing the rectangle? A Single JPEG may contain more than one 2X2 inch rectangles.

Comment: I mean what you want to be saved for later printing. Or do you want to print something which contains several 2x2 inch rectangles?

Comment: @TaW Yeah several 2X2 inch rectangles eg: photos

Comment: Well you need to know the size of your image then and the size you want it to have when printed! There the same formula applies. And the rectangles you want to draw must be drawn in the locations and sizes that result from these sizes! You need to clarify the question to contain this information!

Comment: @TaW Let me explain a sample scenario.Say i need to crop out a portion of an Image(any size) such that the cropped portion should be 2X2 Inches when printed.This Cropped Portion can be duplicated several number of times on an Image which i wish to print(JPEG).But ultimately when the print comes out the size of cropped portion should be 2X2 Inches, the size of the whole Paper does not matter.

Comment: Yes it does matter, or rather the __ratio of pixelsize vs printsize__, because this will determine the pixelsize you need to copy from the original!

Comment: @TaW okay.I will ask the user to print on 4×6” photo paper.

Comment: Fine. But we still need two numbers. Maybe you can provide a size good enough to use 150dpi, which makes most printers' output at least ok..  I'll post an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an image print in the right size by default, it needs to have the right combination of `dpi` and pixels.

Let's look at an example:

```
// aiming at 150dpi and 4x6 inches:
float dpi = 150;
float width = 4;
float height = 6;

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)(dpi * width), (int)(dpi * height)))
{
    // first set the resolution
    bmp.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
    // then create a suitable Graphics object:
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Orange))
    {
        pen.Alignment = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Center;
        G.Clear(Color.FloralWhite);
        // using pixels here:

        Size sz = new System.Drawing.Size((int)dpi * 2 - 1, (int)dpi * 2 - 1);
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), sz));
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 300), sz));
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 600), sz));
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(300, 0), sz));
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(300, 300), sz));
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point(300, 600), sz));

        // alternative code:
        // we can also set the Graphics object to measure stuff in inches;
        G.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
        // or fractions of it, let's use 10th:
        G.PageScale = 0.1f;
        using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.MediumPurple, 1f / dpi * G.PageScale))
        {
            // draw one rectangle offset by an inch:
            G.DrawRectangle(pen2, 10f, 10f, 20f, 20f);
        }

        bmp.Save(@"D:\xxx.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Note that I had to subtract 1 pixel from the drawn size as `DrawRectangle` **overdraws** by 1 pixel!

[image]

Note that the coordinates I draw at depend on the resolution! Also note how the jpeg format creates a lot of smeared colors. `Png`creates crisper results, especially once you print text..

Also note how I had to scale down the `PenWidth` in the alternative code!

Comment: Thanks a lot.So for different paper sizes i will just change the width,height and go on drawing the rectangles.

Comment: Yes. The same goes for printing at better resolution.. Note that the coordinate I draw at depends on the resolution! Also note how the jpeg format creates smeared colors.

Comment: I wanted to ask that.How did you get the value 300?

Comment: okay...But for an A4 sized paper ... what should i do...? Im a Noob in this stuff :)

Comment: [A4](http://www.a4papersize.org/) has 8.267 x 11.692 inches. But your usable printing size will be less, depending on your printer.. Do note that for the alternative code to work we have to set the dpi first, then create the Graphics object!

Comment: okay.Thanks.is it possible for you to modify the code to place maximum images on the output JPEG depending on the paper size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98918/discussion-between-taw-and-techno).